# Array function with multiple conditions for transaction data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a table with customer/contract IDs that contains transactions. A customer has at least one contract (the shell) and at least one contract item (if only shell contract --> contract item= shell contract). The "shell contract" is either "pay" or "free".

Each customer, contract and contract item can appear more than once. For example, a customer can cancel a contract item, take back the cancellation afterwards, or create new contract items, etc.

As mentioned before a customer always has a "shell contract" and within this "shell contract" no, one, or several additional contracts.

My question is now how I can write an array formula, which gives me for each customer whether its shell contract is "pay" or "free".

In the table with the dummy-data the shell contract is the one with "contract_id" 1. The result of a working array formula would be in the column "pay or free for contract_id=1".

As you can see only the rows which include a contract id of 1 are relevant for the corresponding result. The other rows can be ignored.

I have already tried different array formulas but it just won't work the way it should -.- All the other columns in the file are fully dynamic e.g. the column contract status which checks the last transaction_date for a specific customer and specific contract_id. Just that one last formula won't work.

From a logical point of view the formula would work somehow like this:

```
= if customer_id="xyz",
 for each contract_id=1,
 check if contract status="active" or "in cancellation",
 "pay",
 otherwise "free".

pay of free for contract_id=1 customer_id contract_id contract status
pay                           xyz         1           active
pay                           xyz         2           cancelled
pay                           xyz         1           active
pay                           xyz         3           in cancellation
```

Comment: sorry kevin, I'm not sure what you mean by "for each contract_id=1". Are you saying that you would like to check all of the contract_id's for that given customer_id, and if any are '1', then result is "pay"?

Comment: Hi, Tyler, sorry for the misunderstanding.
Of relevance is only the contract_id=1, this ID identifies the "shell contract". If in this line the "contract status" is either "active" or "in cancellation" then in the column "pay or free" for ALL related cells. In the dummy-table above only one customer can be seen ("xyz"). The first column " pay or free" is only determined by the value of contract_id=1 even though this information is not given in the rows wtih contract_id=2 or 3. Thats why array formulas are needed. Thanks a lot for help and your support to clarify the issue.